# Efficient Storage for Eigen's DiagonalMatrix type in C++

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I want to do matrix multiplication with a dense matrix and a diagonal matrix. The diagonal matrix is generated from a vector using `vec.asDiagonal()`.

I am wondering if the DiagonalMatrix type stores just the diagonal, or is it a dense matrix full of zeroes, except for the diagonal? I imagine that a DiagonalMatrix should be a child of Eigen's SparseMatrix. I searched for documentation and found this

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=SpecialMatrix#Diagonal_matrix, suggesting a DiagonalMatrix inherits from MatrixBase, and not SparseMatrix. Does this mean the memory storage is inefficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DiagonalMatrix` stores only the diagonal as a dense vector. Both the return type of `vec.asDiagonal()` and `DiagonalMatrix` inherit from `DiagonalBase` and not `MatrixBase` ([doc](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DiagonalMatrix.html)). They are essentially the same: one stores a reference to a dense vector whereas the other is the owner of the diagonal vector.